# Looping through mysql_fetch_array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

So I have the following:

```
$i = 0;
$records = mysql_num_rows($sections_query);
$row_sections = mysql_fetch_array($sections_query);
    foreach ($row_sections as $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

The value of $records becomes 4 after execution and the DB has 2 columns per row.  The first column value is 'section_id' and the second is 'section_name'.

I want to write a loop that will print out the value of 'section_name' like-

```
echo "<h3>" . $row_sections[section_name]; . "</h3>";
```

within the loop, so basically I'll have 3 h3's each containing the 4 different values in 'section_name'

And maybe foreach() isn't the best loop to use?  Anyway, I'm confused.

Hope that makes sense, and thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$records = mysql_num_rows($sections_query);
while($row_sections = mysql_fetch_array($sections_query))
{
    echo "<h3>" . $row_sections['section_name'] . "</h3>";
}
```

That will go through each row and print the Section Name.

Comment: You left out a { and there's a semi-colon in the echo line out of place but, when it worked fine once I fixed that.

Thanks!!