# mysql_fetch_array printing only first result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looping through mysql_fetch_array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208236/looping-through-mysql-fetch-array-in-php)

I have a simple join query that should echo out each array result in a `foreach` loop. The array is not empty. Printing the array count works -- there are 801 results. However, actually printing out the rows either above or within the `foreach` only prints the first result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$listQuery = "SELECT r.email_address
            FROM wholesale_accounts a
            LEFT JOIN wholesale_register r ON r.register_id = a.register_id
            WHERE r.email_address != ''
            ORDER BY r.email_address";            
$listResult = mysql_query($listQuery);
//print_r($listResult); // prints (Resource ID #21)
//exit;

$rows = mysql_fetch_array($listResult, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$count = mysql_num_rows($listResult);
//print_r($count); // prints 801
print_r($rows); // only prints first email address
exit;

foreach($rows as $row) {
    print_r($row); // prints email address          
}
```

Comment: It is better for you to pick a good book or tutorial on any language of your choice than to post questions like this here. It shows you've not been paying attention to what you read or you didn't take the pain to understand how things work. Technology is moving fast and this one is old - embrace PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Thanks @codingbiz. It sounds like you need some more information. I am attempting to fix a broken piece of old site that I did not build. That's my main job description. If I had built this site, it would be PDO. I have debugged this many ways -- that's why I am posting here. But thanks for your opinion anyway.

Comment: I was being honest with you mate. I learned that truth when I joined SO few months ago - we need to be able defend what we know so others can learn from us and trust our judgment. Hope you got the problem solved? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` gets one row at a time so you need to put that in a loop

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($listResult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   print_r($rows);
}
```

Comment: A `while` loop didn't quite get it, but using `list()` with it worked. Here's what I ended up with:


`while (list($email_address) = mysql_fetch_row($listResult)) {   
 echo $email_address . '<br>';
}`